# Partial XML parsing giving an element not bound exception

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm trying to parse an XML document with DSpace XOAI library. This is the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
   ...
   <ListRecords>
      <record>
         <header>
            ...
         </header>
         <metadata>
            <crossref xmlns="http://www.crossref.org/xschema/1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.crossref.org/xschema/1.1 http://www.crossref.org/schema/unixref1.1.xsd">
               ...
            </crossref>
         </metadata>
      </record>
   </ListRecords>
</OAI-PMH>
```

From what I could deduce from debugging, each metadata node is parsed individually by XOAI library. And, in that context, I get this error (which makes sense, because the xsi namespace is defined in parent OAI-PMH node):

```
ERROR: 'The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "crossref" is not bound.'
```

For what I could understand from the library source code, it uses the Oracle java javax.xml.transform.Transformer to make the transformations. We can set any Transformer to be executed.

I'm already using an XSLT file for transforming the input XML in the format expected by the library. However, I couldn't find a way to create a rule in XSLT to ignore the xsi:schemaLocation that is causing the error.

The other option is create a new Transformer in Java. I was looking at Transformer.setOutputProperty, but I couldn't make a working configuration that ignores this error in crossref node.

Do you guys know how can I correctly parse the contents of crossref node in that local context?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the problem seems specific to the use of DSpace XOAI, zou might want to see whether that software has a support forum or if there exist tags here on Stackoverflow related to that software then use them.

Comment: I think you need to add the xmlns:xsi declaration to the crossref element as well.

Comment: @MartinHonnen it might be the case. But the DSpace XOAI is not being actively developed, so I don't think I'll find an answer there.

Comment: @daniu yes, by adding the xmlns:xsi declaration to crossref node or removing the xsi:schemaLocation from crossref node the parser can parse the document without any error. The problem with this solution is that I receive this response from a webservice, so I can't tamper it before processing.